# function return value from singleshot call

Tags: python, function, user-interface, return-value

I am new to python. I have created a ui file in QT designer and using it in python. In order to let the GUI get an update, I am using singleShot;

```
self.lableTop.setText('Starting To program... Please Wait')
self.textEditInfo.append('Mem programming started')
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.programMem())
```

where programMem is some function which returns 0 on success.
Is there any way I can get the return value of this function using above call.
Is this the right way to let gui updated before it calls function?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. No need for singleshot.
The trick is to call

```
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

for an update.